# .cmd script output only goes to pipe occasionally

Tags: command-line, batch, pipe

I'm having a problem with a .cmd script only occasionally passing it's output through a pipe. The script is auto generated by npm and it runs jshint using node. Here's the script:

```
:: Created by npm, please don't edit manually.
@IF EXIST "%~dp0\node.exe" (
  "%~dp0\node.exe"  "%~dp0\node_modules\jshint\bin\hint" %*
) ELSE (
  node  "%~dp0\node_modules\jshint\bin\hint" %*
)
```

Calling this script as `jshint test.js` always produces the desired output. However, it seems to not always get passed via a pipe. For example, `jshint test.js | cat` only produces output perhaps 10% of the time. Interestingly, `jshint test.js > .jshintjunk & type .jshintjunk | cat` works fine, but I'd rather not have the intermediate file.

Any idea how I can resolve this?

Comment: What is `cat` on Windows?? Cygwin?

Comment: It's actually cat from MSYS. http://oldwiki.mingw.org/index.php/MSYS I get the same behavior piping into other programs as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
echo. | jshint test.js | cat
```

That also happened to me and I solved it passing *echo.*.